# getJSON on phonegap error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cordova, getjson

**http://example.com/json.js**

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones"
        }
    ]
}
```

and ajax:

```
<script>
(function() {
  var jsonurl = "http://example.com/json.js";
  $.getJSON( jsonurl , {
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "#mydiv" ).append( item.employees.firstname+" - "+item.employees.lastname+"<br>" );
        if ( i === 3 ) { //number of items
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
</script>
```

But it dose not works.
I get this error on console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/last.js?format=json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.3:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

so I read I must change URL like this

```
http://example.com/json.js?jsoncallback=?
```

error gones But new error in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>   http://example.com/last.js?jsoncallback=jQuery111306243502511642873_1446327132484&format=json&_=1446327132485

Comment: We need more information.  In my opinion, there isn't enough to work with here given your code seems fine.

Comment: not all API's serve `jsonp`. Do you control the api you are trying to access?

Comment: yes, that file is on my server. I read this article now: http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax            should I  change my .htaccess hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP to read the json file to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
    <?php
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
     }   

     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
     header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
     exit(0);
     }
    $myfile = fopen("json.js", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("json.js"));
    fclose($myfile);
   ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This will add CORS to all your files serving form the server, allowing your cross domain request to return the files contents.

Comment: No I don't belive the OP knows about JSONP. The OP has just added `callback=?` without rewriting the code for a JSONP request. A callback can't even have the value `?`... I don't believe the OP understands the issue, so I provided the relevant links for the user to learn about the relevant subjects.

Comment: And you're right, however until the OP clarified their position(which they hadn't at the time of this answer), the answer was wrong.  However, at this moment it is obvious the OP doesn't understand the topics at hand, and thus I'm deleting all my prior comments as they are now obsolete.

Comment: Your new answer is one of the reasons I'm sure CORS was developed in the first place.  To prevent breaches of security, as this answer would create.  If the user is serving an API then the correct answer is to limit requests to that specific file.  Not everything under the sun.

Comment: I'm making it very clear that this will add CORS to all files.